# How to fixed android RecyclerView list height?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

How to make  `RecyclerView` list height fixed? In `RecyclerView`  list I have one `TextView` for showing heading. I am using custom adapter to set data into it. But if data increases in `TextView` height of `RecyclerView` list gets increases. That is height of changes according to data size.  I don’t want that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If data increases in TextView, then there's no way to set a fixed size to your RecyclerView. It will adapt according to the size of the View it contains. You could limit the size of the TextView adding the following property to your TextView

```
android:maxLength="15"
```

Or you could set the singleLine property to true, so that the text stays in a single line only

```
android:singleLine="true"
android:ellipsize="end"
```

Then the TextView wont increase in size even if the data does and your layout wont be affected.